# Implement Two EventHandlers

Tags: java, oop, events, javafx, event-handling

I am trying to implement `EventHandler<MouseEvent>`, and `EventHandler<KeyEvent>` in the same class. However, I can't, since it says `EventHandler` is a single class. How can I create a class that is both a mouse event handler and a key event handler?

Comment: You can't, but you could make 2 nested/anonymous classes that implement each.

Comment: It's not really clear why you would want to do this.

Comment: @James_D so I can have a class that is both a mouse event handler and a key event handler, since an EventHandler<?> is required for JavaFX event handling

Comment: Why would you want such a thing though? The methods `setOnXXX(...)` all require specific event handlers (with a specific event type), and the `addEventHandler(EventType<T>, EventHandler<? super T>)` method (and similarly `addEventFilter(...)`) take specific types of event handler too. Suppose you had a class that implemented both, how would you actually use it? If the behavior is identical for either type of event, you can just use a `EventHandler<Event>` or `EventHandler<InputEvent>`; if the behavior is different, you may as well have two handler classes.

Comment: @James_D Oh true, I didn't think of using a generic Event... thanks

Comment: Alternatively just define the behavior in a method: `private void someMethod(Event e) { ...}` and use lambdas: `node.setOnKeyPressed(e -> someMethod(e));`, `node.setOnMouseClicked(e -> someMethod(e));`, or even method references: `node.setOnKeyPressed(this::someMethod);` etc.

Comment: @James_D that's actually what I ended up doing, I just wanted a more "object-oriented design"